# Can't navigate to a href, url just loses parameters

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, anchor, href

I've got an a tag in react which when clicked won't take me to the href it just removes all the paremeters in the url after the ?. eg. I'm on: http://localhost:6006/iframe.html?selectedKind=Survey&selectedStory=...etc.
and then it takes me to http://localhost:6006/iframe.html? on click, instead of to google.com

I've also tried using window.open on a button click and it's the same thing, if I do window.open just normally than that works. Any ideas?

`exitUrl = 'https://www.google.com';`

`target = '_self';`

> works

```
        window.open(this.exitUrl, this.target);
```

> Don't work

`<a href={this.exitUrl} target={this.target}>`

`<button onClick={() =>window.open(this.exitUrl, this.target)}`

Also tried setting the onclick of the anchor to the same, and still doesn't work:

```
let anchor = document.getElementById('wtfisgoinon');
anchor.onclick = window.open(this.exitUrl, this.target);
```

Comment: Where are you trying it? On Chrome or Firefox? If yes, did you tried this on incognito mode? I've tried your code on my application and on chrome and incognito mode it works

Comment: And it works when I was using "<a href={this.exitUrl} target={this.target}>". With button it works the same like yours

Comment: Ah I haven’t tried different browsers will give that a go

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna open it in same it's not necessary use "target" property.

Just use:

```
<a href={this.exitUrl}> Exit </a>
```

Comment: I have target switching between ‘_self’ and ‘_blank’ depending on setting

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and when I've removed "target" it works. I've done another function in component:

```
googleTag() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com')
}
```

And I've made button like yours:

```
<button onClick={() => this.googleTag()} />
```

Now, when I'm clicking on these button, it opens new tab with Google URL.

Comment: I require target, see other answer

Comment: So you can use only "<a href={this.exitUrl} target={this.target}>". It wokrs for me with target.

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into the same issue. Using `target="_self"`, I found that all URL parameters were being removed.

However, I found out that `target="_top"` will work and redirect to the correct URL, including the URL parameters.